# Error while installing jupyter (Command errored out with exit status 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to install `jupyter` and getting errors:

```
python --version:
python 3.6.8

pip --version
pip 20.3.3 from /home/my/rep/prj/venv/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python  3.6)


which ipython3:
/usr/bin/ipython3
```

I'm trying to install jupyter:

```
pip install jupyter

 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
/home/my/rep/prj/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize....
command     
....
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output
```

How can I fix it and install jupyter ?

Comment: Can you see *any other* error messages *before* the "Command errored out with exit status 1" line? That line is the generic error for everything, it gets printed out for all kinds of errors, which isn't useful. There is usually other errors/info in the lines before that, that are more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: Please try to provide a (short) explanation of why you think that would help OP.